# /dev/null folder doesn't exist. Should I create it?

Tags: linux, cron

I am pretty new to the Rasperry Pi (and linux in general). I am currently using it as an irc bouncer. I have set a `cron` entry to make it check to see if [`znc`](http://wiki.znc.in/ZNC) is running every 10 mins.

```
*/10 * * * *  /usr/bin/znc >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Everything seems to be working fine. But I noticed that there is no `null` folder in `dev`. Does this need to be created?

Comment: What OS distribution are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I noticed that there is no null folder in dev

Because you are looking at the partition while the system is not running.  `/dev` contains device nodes created by the kernel, mostly during boot.  They are not real files in the sense of being a sequence of bytes stored somewhere, which is why they usually appear to be of 0 size.

When the system is not running, `/dev` should be empty.  When it is running, a special file system of type `devtmpfs` is mounted there.  It is unmounted at shutdown or will otherwise cease to exist if the system stops since it exists only in memory.

> Should I create it?

No.  Anything put into `/dev` when the system is down will be hidden under the mount point anyway.  Also, `/dev/null`, as implied, is not a normal file.

Comment: After reading your comment, I decided to look further. I was figured `null` was a folder and tried to navigate there, unsuccessfully. After going to the parent folder, I can see it there. Feel a little silly now, but I guess is all in the learning process.

Comment: Ah, you tried something like `cd /dev/null` -- that wouldn't work.  The purpose of `/dev/null` is to provide a sort of drain for unwanted output.  Anything written to it is just discarded.   It's sometimes important for a backgrounded process to not have its output channels cut-off (which is what would happen if they aren't redirected).  So `2>&1` redirects the standard error channel to the standard output one, and `> /dev/null` directs that to oblivion; the output isn't cut-off, but it is discarded.

Answer (score 1):

The /dev/null is a special file, not a directory. If you accidentally removed it you can re-create it with this command

`mknod /dev/null c 1 3`

Comment: Again, **do not bother doing this** unless the system is running -- in which case `/dev/null` will already exist (presuming you haven't intentionally done something odd).